# Add watermark and resize image in PHP

Tags: php, image-resizing, watermark

I need to add watermark on uploaded image and also resize it to make thumbnails and icons from that watermarked image. Below is my function code which is adding watermark but I can't find out how to resize image to given height and width:

```
function watermark_image_new($target, $wtrmrk_file, $newcopy, $extension, $w = 0, $h = 0) {
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng($wtrmrk_file);
imagealphablending($watermark, false);
imagesavealpha($watermark, true);
//resize code
if ($w != 0) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($target);
    if ($extension == 'jpeg' || $extension == 'jpg') {
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    } else if ($extension == 'png') {
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
    }
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $width, $height);
}
$img_w = imagesx($img);
$img_h = imagesy($img);
$wtrmrk_w = imagesx($watermark);
$wtrmrk_h = imagesy($watermark);
$dst_x = ($img_w / 2) - ($wtrmrk_w / 2); // For centering the watermark on any image
$dst_y = ($img_h / 2) - ($wtrmrk_h / 2); // For centering the watermark on any image
imagecopy($img, $watermark, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $wtrmrk_w, $wtrmrk_h);
if ($extension == 'jpeg' || $extension == 'jpg') {
    imagejpeg($img, $newcopy, 100);
} else if ($extension == 'png') {
    imagepng($img, $newcopy);
}
imagedestroy($img);
imagedestroy($watermark);
}
```

Comment: I googled "resize image in PHP" and found [Imagick::resizeImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php)

Comment: @gregn3 can you please explain how it works? it has some different parameters, what was their use?

Comment: You're right, it's different from imagecopyresampled(). What is the exact problem with imagecopyresampled()? (I found the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) for it too)

Comment: @gregn3 My issue is my code is not resizing image, it create image as it is with watermark  on it.

Comment: Are you sure you are supplying the correct parameters to imagecopyresampled() ? (There might be a bug in your code... I don't know)

Comment: @gregn3 oh yes! I corrected it, i missed $width, $height to copy here, but in real code they were present and still no change in image size.

Comment: I would try to test imagecopyresampled() separately, until it works. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! According to my findings, imagecopyresampled is returning true, i think issue occurs on code which implement watermark.. it is adding watermark on original image and saving it not the one we resized.

Comment: Yes I see you were using **$img** in imagecopy() instead of **$dst**. I'm glad it's resolved now. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155696/discussion-between-umair-malik-and-gregn3).

Answer (score 0):

A simple example to use Imagick for solve your case. To render Watermark and resize it and output the changed image

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage("/path/to/image.jpg");
$watermark = new Imagick();
$watermark->readImage("/path/to/watermark.png");
// how big are the images?
$iWidth = $image->getImageWidth();
$iHeight = $image->getImageHeight();
$wWidth = $watermark->getImageWidth();
$wHeight = $watermark->getImageHeight();
if ($iHeight < $wHeight || $iWidth < $wWidth) {
 // resize the watermark
   $watermark->scaleImage($iWidth, $iHeight);
// get new size
$wWidth = $watermark->getImageWidth();
   $wHeight = $watermark->getImageHeight();
}
// calculate the position
$x = ($iWidth - $wWidth) / 2;
$y = ($iHeight - $wHeight) / 2;
$image->compositeImage($watermark, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $x, $y);
header("Content-Type: image/" . $image->getImageFormat());
echo $image;
```

Comment: While this does add the watermark to the image it does not resize the original image to a smaller dimension, which is what the OP requested.

Comment: in order to fulfill the last case one would only have to execute $image->scaleImage again after  $image->compositeImage